# Register On-Click Event with jQuery - Not Firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Should be a quickie ...

1) I created a new project in VS2013 using MVC.
2) I added the following code to the bottom of the default Home\Index.cshtml that is created with the project template.

```
<button class="myalertclass">Alert me</button>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")">
    $(document).on('click', '.myalertclass', function (e) {
        alert('Hello you');
    })
</script>
```

I was now expecting that when I click the "Alert me" button, I'll get a message box with "Hello you", but no such joy.

The problem is that when I click the button, the event is not fired.  I guess I'm missing some wiring somewhere, but am stumped.

Comment: You can't specify a `src` _and_ a body for your script element... so, use two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What if script tag has both "src" and inline script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540581/what-if-script-tag-has-both-src-and-inline-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT) (emphasis mine):

> The script may be defined within the contents of the `SCRIPT` element or in an external file. If the `src` attribute is not set, user agents must interpret the contents of the element as the script. **If the `src` has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents and retrieve the script via the URI.**

That's to say, you can't specify both a `src` *and* a body for your `script` element and expect both to work... so, use two separate `script` elements.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.myalertclass', function (e) {
        alert('Hello you');
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not include inline scripts in a referenced script tag. Try this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")"></script>

<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.myalertclass', function (e) {
        alert('Hello you');
    })
</script>
```

Comment: duplicate of @canon's answer