# Why isn't this very simple JQuery working?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I was trying to pass the width of a page as a variable to C# code behind asp.net, and was only receiving empty strings. I narrowed down to the problem that the JQuery function is simply not firing. I changed it to the simplest code I could just to test if the function was doing anything:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
           alert("hello");
    });
</script>
```

And yet, it still does nothing.

1. I've included JQuery
2. I've triple checked my syntax
3. No errors are reported in the console
4. I looked through the other similar SO 'facepalm' questions, but none of their solutions work (see above)

What incredibly obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: [Pertinent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19689613/621962).

Comment: there is a good article from John Resig regarding this behaviour: http://ejohn.org/blog/degrading-script-tags/

Comment: This got closed faster than i could find a more appropriate duplicate, but I feel that this is more closely related to [a different question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540581/what-if-script-tag-has-both-src-and-inline-script).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't simultaneously set the `[src]` attribute and include contents for the `<script>` element.

If you need two scripts, you need to use two separate `<script>` elements.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        alert("hello");
    });
</script>
```

As per the [HTML5 spec on the `<script>` element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-script-element):

> If there is no `src` attribute, depends on the value of the `type` attribute, but must match script content restrictions.
>   If there is a `src` attribute, the element must be either empty or contain only script documentation that also matches script content restrictions.

Comment: Yep, here's the facepalm. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
           alert("hello");
    });
</script>
```

Here is a post that explains this clearly-

[What if script tag has both "src" and inline script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540581/what-if-script-tag-has-both-src-and-inline-script)