# Very simple jQuery function is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code in a .html file, and I am then opening it with a browser. Why do I not receive the "Hello World" alert when the page loads? All I see is the "Test" text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            alert("Hello World!");
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
        Test
    </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put your function in an extra script tag.

Comment: add a `<script type="text/javascript">` between this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">` and `$(document)`

Comment: hahahaha, the best duplicate I have ever seen!

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare the `[src]` attribute *and* have the contents of a `<script>` element execute.

You need to use a second `<script>` element:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Hello World!");
    });
</script>
```

---

**NOTE:** when using the `document.ready` callback in jQuery, it's advisable to use the shorthand version to alias `jQuery` to `$` for greater script compatibility:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    alert('Hello World');
});
```

Comment: [hmm, this answer feels oddly familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21488173/497418).

Answer (score 1):

change it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Hello World!");
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: but **why** does that work?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">           
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    alert("Hello World!");
               });
         </script>
     </head>
     <body>
         <p>Test</p>
     </body>
</html>
```

With first script tag we LOAD jquery. 
In second script

Answer (score 0):

As some of the answers already stated, you can't have the browser view the `src` and the contents through one script tag. Here is the `W3C` information on it:

> **The script may be defined within the contents of the SCRIPT element or in an external file.** If the src attribute is not set, user agents
>   must interpret the contents of the element as the script. If the src
>   has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents and
>   retrieve the script via the URI.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html