# Integrating HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

so i'm trying to use an API to get a random word (http://randomword.setgetgo.com) and then use it to store the random word as a variable in javascript and then print that variable to the screen. My Code is

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">
    var word = $.get("http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php");
    document.WriteIn(word);
</script>
```

However nothing is being written to the HTML document.

Could anyone help explain this a little bit and point me in the write direciton to get this working? I'm just starting to learn web development.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't this very simple JQuery working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488145/why-isnt-this-very-simple-jquery-working)

Comment: 1) fix your script tag (use one to load jquery, then another to enclose your scripts on-page) 2) you are attempting output a string likely before it's been retrieved from the server.

Answer (score 4):

Thre are multiple problmes...

- [script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) cannot have both src and content - see [doc for src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-src)
- you need to use a callback to handle the response of an ajax call - [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)
- if it is a cross domain request, make sure cors support is enabled in the target site

so

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.get("http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php", function(content){
        $('body').append(content)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php. Origin http://run.plnkr.co is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: @Jess because you are trying to make cross domain ajax request... which is not permitted by Same Origin Policy

Comment: Oh yes I know.  Sorry I should have posted more info.  I was documenting it for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Put your scripts between <\script> tags, usually in the -section of your document. Then call it from the point you like.

I recommend looking at some tutorials, since these are the very basics that bug you

Comment: It is. Had some problems in original posts formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code in `<script>` tags.

You also need to make sure that you have included the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the random word in a `div`?

Like so:

```
$("#theDiv").text(word);
```

And you need to put your code in a separate `<script>` element that does not have a `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can't both set the `[src]` attribute and the contents of the `<script>` tag. If you need two scripts, you need to use two script tags:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var word = $.get("http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php");
    document.WriteIn(word);
</script>
```

Additionally, `$.get` runs asynchronously and will not return the contents of the url request.

`document.WriteIn` is not a function, unless you've defined it somewhere.

If you just need to dump the contents of the `GET` request after the executing script, you could use:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function () {
        var $script;
        $script = $('script').last();
        $.get('http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php', function (data) {
            $script.append(data);
        });
    }());
</script>
```