# Implementing FileSaver.js saveAs() function into HTML script

Tags: javascript, html, blob, filesaver.js

Right now I am attempting to save information from an HTML page that I am creating to a text document, using javascript and the FileSaver.js package. I am not very well versed in HTML and am completely new to javascript, so odds are that I am making some egregious mistake. At the moment, I have eligrey's [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) file in the same directory as the HTML file that I am working from, so I should be able to call it simply as "FileSaver.js" in HTML.

Right now I am working from something like this:

```html
//some irrelevant text

<script src="FileSaver.js">
  function download(){
    
    //alert("hello world");
    //this alert line was to test the function call
    //the alert actually appears when the <script> tag
    // has no src field labeled. Just an observation.
    
    var blob = new Blob(["Hello World"],{type:"text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob,"helloworld.txt");
   }
</script>

//some more irrelevant text

<input type="button" value="download" onclick="download();"/>
/*from this button I want to gather information from input text fields on the page.
 I already know how to do that, the problem is creating and, subsequently, 
downloading the text file I am trying to create. For simplicity's sake, the text I am 
capturing in this example is hardcoded as "hello world"*/

//last of irrelevant text
//oh, and don't try to run this snippet :P
```

I also have eligrey's Blob.js file available in my immediate working directory as well, just in case.

As of now, the button does nothing. I am fairly sure that I am calling the function correctly considering I could receive the javascript alert text, at least when the script tag had no src. If I do add a src, absolutely nothing happens. The browser that I am testing from is the latest Google Chrome stable build (43.0 I think) on Windows XP. Please inform me of anything that I am missing and/or doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I might add your XHTML style of void elements (`<element />`) is probably incorrect. I assume that you’re using HTML5, which certainly doesn’t require it. Technically, there is an XHTML5, but that requires the document to be served as XML, which, I trust is not happening here. Using the closing slash in a document served as HTML, is simply noise which the browser politely ignores. And, as noted below, it can also get you into trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a script tag with a `src` attribute and content inside the tag. Split it into two separate script tags. See [What if script tag has both "src" and inline script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540581/what-if-script-tag-has-both-src-and-inline-script)

Note that `<script>` [cannot be a self-closing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

```
<script src="FileSaver.js"></script>
<script>
  function download(){

    //alert("hello world");
    //this alert line was to test the function call
    //the alert actually appears when the <script> tag
    // has no src field labeled. Just an observation.

    var blob = new Blob(["Hello World"],{type:"text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob,"helloworld.txt");
   }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you, as you have written it actually works! I had tried   <script src="FileSaver.js"/>   instead of    <script src="FileSaver.js"></script>   as you have, but didn't work, so it's kind of strange that closing it as such works. oh well, Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, that's another thing, script tags can't be self-closing, just like divs, only specific tags can be self-closing ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work Typically only tags that cannot have any content can be self-closing, such as, `input, br, img...`