# Call javascript from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a HTML file with the content:

```
<script src="http://spelprogrammering.nu/simple.js">
function test()
{
//Function stuff
}
</script>
```

However, I'd like to write all my javascript (*Function test*) in a separate document (.js). *How do I refer to, or call, this separate file so I get the same result as if the code was directly in the HTML?*

I need the http://spelprogrammering.nu/simple.js to ease the graphics handling in *function test*.

Comment: <script src=" http://spelprogrammering.nu/simple.js"></script>

Comment: Many times this is right above closing body tag, or as close as possible to this

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob That depends on what he's trying to do.

Comment: A script tag that has a `src` attribute **can not** also contain javascript, then it won't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What if script tag has both "src" and inline script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540581/what-if-script-tag-has-both-src-and-inline-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the html  section, refer to the file that contains your javascript, I'm assuming the html file is in the same folder as that containing your script.

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

> If the script is in a different folder...

```
<script src="/path/to/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your solution solved my problem! Also found a bug in the web link source, contributing to the error.

Comment: @billven Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You already have what you need in your source.

```
<script src="http://spelprogrammering.nu/simple.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://spelprogrammering.nu/simple.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Where main.js contains your function.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It answers the question exactly as asked, where the OP wants to include a library and his own code in two separate files.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you say that? in this case you need to make difrent script calling your .js

```
<code>
<script src="http://spelprogrammering.nu/simple.js"></script>
<script src="http://spelprogrammering.nu/other.js"></script>
<script src="http://spelprogrammering.nu/other2.js"></script>
```